# Retrieve value stored in array with jquery index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks on a `div` tag, I want to store the corresponding `id` value in var `current`, so that it can later be used to iterate to that index, and so that div can be shown and hidden.

**html**

```
<div class="gallerypreview" id="1"></div>
<div class="gallerypreview" id="2"></div>
<div class="gallerypreview" id="3"></div>
```

**js**

```
var images = new Array();

$(document).ready( function(){

$('.gallerypreview').each(function() {
    images.push($(this).attr("id"));
});

$('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
var current = $('.gallerypreview').index(this);
});

});
```

How would I go about retrieving the div `id` from this clicked div? I can get the index number fine, but I cannot find the value of the index using any functions that utilizes the index #.

Comment: Never begin an ID or class with a number (http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1418261). It can cause some browsers to not interpret the ID properly.

Comment: It looks like you are coding yourself in circles just to get a reference to a clicked div. It doesn't seem like you need the array, the iterator, even the element ids. You can get a reference to the clicked element by simply: `var current; $('.gallerypreview').click(function(){current = this;});` What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
var current = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Inside the click callback function `$(this)` references the specific DOM object that was clicked. So a simple `.attr("id")` will get you the id for the clicked div (stored in the variable `current`).

Hope that helps

Comment: I need to get the id from the index only... this is bascially for an image slider, once the first div class is clicked, i need to use a moveLeft and moveRight function to find the index and use it to hide/show the next index, not the one clicked. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = new Array();

$(function() {

   $('.gallerypreview').each(function() {
      images.push($(this).attr("id"));
   });

   var current = null;
   $('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
      current = $(this).attr('id');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7fPL5/

Addresses the click issue, as well as changes the IDs to valid HTML/CSS IDs (stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1418261).

JS

```
var images = new Array();

$(document).ready( function(){

$('.gallerypreview').each(function() {
    images.push($(this).attr("id"));
});

$('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
var current = $('.gallerypreview').index(this);
    alert(current.attr("id"));
});

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="gallerypreview" id="one">1</div>
<div class="gallerypreview" id="two">2</div>
<div class="gallerypreview" id="three">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope of the variable `current` declare it appropriately:

```
var images = new Array(), current;
```

Then change the following:

```
$('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
var current = $('.gallerypreview').index(this);
});
```

To:

```
$('.gallerypreview').on('click', function() {
    current = this.id;
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vRh8m/)